# C# Monitor ECX register every time breakpoint is fired

Tags: c#, assembly

How do I monitor current ECX register in C# at given ASM opcode?

Say, I have a:

```
FF8.exe+69DD8 - push ecx
```

Using any ready debugger I can do a breakpoint at given opcode and watch registers.

But I need to make an automation software to:

> Catch every time 'push ecx' is called and add it to table with the time it was called to know how often is it called.
>
> It's something like cut-scene with different sounds being played, and we need to know what's the time the sounds are played, one after another

*Why I can't use ready softwares for this?*

Because when I breakpoint 'push ecx', (note: ecx register) and then step over I lose whole timing. I need to do a table with detailed times in which this opcode is accesed.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: I want to do a software that counts it by using C#

Comment: Sounds like you want to write your own specialized debugger that does logging

Comment: Sort of, but a simple one only for data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After four years I am getting back to respond to my own question- Yes, we have to create our own debugger. 
It's as simple as calling P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool DebugActiveProcess(int dwProcessId);
```

1. Get process id (pId) and call DebugActiveProcess:

   ```
   Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(args[0]);
   bool bAttached = pinvokes.DebugActiveProcess(processes[0].Id);
   ```
2. Create new struct of [DEBUG_EVENT](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DEBUG_EVENT.html) - it would contain all the data about breakpoint
3. Wait for debug event in a while loop:

   ```
   WaitForDebugEvent(ref debug, 0xFFFFFFFF);
   ```
4. The breakpoint 0xCC opcode will trigger the EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT. You now have the threadId associated with given exception. You have to now get the thread context by [GetThreadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext)- the CONTEXT structure will now contain CPU registers including **ECX**. You just need to add p/invoke for GetThreadContext and structure for CONTEXT. Full structure and an example can be seen here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetThreadContext.html

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   static extern bool GetThreadContext(IntPtr hThread, ref CONTEXT lpContext);
   ```

The process code will break on every debugging event even on DLL_LOAD. To set a breakpoint at given address you have to actually write an `INT 3` opcode. To do that you have to open process in R/W and inject `0xCC` to process memory. Use OpenProcess p/invoke and WriteProcessMemory p/invoke:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
     ProcessAccessFlags processAccess,
     bool bInheritHandle,
     int processId
);
public static IntPtr OpenProcess(Process proc, ProcessAccessFlags flags)
{
     return OpenProcess(flags, false, proc.Id);
}

[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
    VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
    VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
    DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
    CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
    SetQuota = 0x00000100,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
  IntPtr hProcess,
  IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
  byte[] lpBuffer,
  Int32 nSize,
  out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
  IntPtr hProcess,
  IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object lpBuffer,
  int dwSize,
  out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

Now we have everything required to open, write opcode and break when any thread arrive on that position:

```
IntPtr procHwnd = pinvokes.OpenProcess(processes[0], pinvokes.ProcessAccessFlags.All);
WriteProcessMemory(procHwnd, new IntPtr(0x469DD8), new byte[] { 0xCC }, 1, out IntPtr lpnum);
```

the lpAddress should be absolute virtual address- that means that in the question there's `FF8.exe+69DD8`, so we need to get IMAGE_BASE for selected module which in this case is "FF8.exe" and then add 0x69DD8 to that IMAGE_BASE. Naturally every 32-bit non ASLR processes have IMAGE_BASE set at `0x400000`. For ASLR activated processes you have to get process modules and get the BaseAddress like this:

```
           foreach(var mod in processes[0].Modules)
            {
                if ((mod as ProcessModule).ModuleName == args[3])
                {
                    image_base = (mod as ProcessModule).BaseAddress;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

where args[3] == "FF8.exe"- this should return 0x400000 for non-ASLR processes on 32bit

Comment: It's not clear how this is supposed to answer your question as it doesn't do anything to  monitor ECX.

Comment: Oh, right- I'm so sorry, I just focused on debug events and totally forgot that it's not everything that has to be done to directly read the CPU registers. I edited my answer with additional step